# What is the purpose of RC in series on FPGA output pin?

Tags: fpga, filter, io

Does the RC branch connected to the output as shown serve as a low pass filter? Shouldn't the output be tapped after the 50 Ohm resistor if it were to be used as a filter?

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 3):

If the resistor value was **anything other** than either 50 ohm, 75 ohm, 100 ohm or 120 ohm I might give the answer that it was for general deglitching of an IO line.

So, it's probably a 50 ohm data termination that doesn't screw up the DC levels of the data signals (because of the 1200 pF capacitor) but does significantly cut-down on the transmission-line reflections. I've also seen as 51 ohm in series with 100 pF (and I've used similar to fix some rogue RS485 problems): -

[image]

Picture taken from [**Here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=data+termination+methods&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-q8Kp86vRAhWMCMAKHbn3DvQQ_AUICCgB&biw=1224&bih=893#tbm=isch&q=transmission+line+termination+methods&imgrc=Of8QWAIeD_olQM%3A).

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to say without the full context. However the device is described as a Device Under Test this leads me to believe that what is put on the output pin is a standardized load to test the response of the device.